# Adding future events that have not happened in the past in Facebook Prophet - Python

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-prophet

I want to be able to give the forecast a "bump" using special events. However in the [Prophet Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html#modeling-holidays-and-special-events), the following paragraph can be found:

*"It must include all occurrences of the holiday, both in the past (back as far as the historical data go) and in the future (out as far as the forecast is being made)"*

However, Let's assume I only have historical events for black month but in the future I want to make a custom campaign that has not happened before. I tried doing this regularly by adding an event data frame like this

```
blackmonth = pd.DataFrame({
  'holiday': 'blackmonth',
  'ds': pd.to_datetime(['2018-11-15',
                        '2019-11-15',
                        '2020-11-15',
                        '2021-11-15',
                        '2022-11-15']),
  'lower_window': -15,
  'upper_window': 15,
})

customcampaign = pd.DataFrame({
  'holiday': 'customcampaign',
  'ds': pd.to_datetime([
                        '2022-11-28']),
  'lower_window': -1,
  'upper_window': 1,
})


holidays = pd.concat((blackmonth, customcampaign))
```

But looking at the event effects on the forecast there is no effect from the custom campaign.

```
var = forecast[(forecast['blackmonth'] + forecast['customcampaign']).abs() > 0][
          ['ds', 'blackmonth', 'customcampaign']][-10:]

var.tail()


Out[84]: 
             ds    blackmonth  customcampaign
1790 2022-11-26  1.909773e+07             0.0
1791 2022-11-27  2.042286e+07             0.0
1792 2022-11-28  1.782498e+07             0.0
1793 2022-11-29  2.240203e+07             0.0
1794 2022-11-30  8.375616e+06             0.0
```

I assume this is because the model had no previous custom campaigns to train on. Is there a way to add event effects that have not occured before, in Facebook Prophet?